# Eclipse Source Editor: Some items are Shown as StrikeThrough. How Come?

Tags: eclipse

I've noticed a strange behavior in the Eclipse source editor. In particular, some items show as strikethrough text.

Some Examples:

**In Imports:**
[image: strikethrough1]

**In Methods:**
[image]

*No lint errors are indicated and the code works just fine.* Has anybody seen this? Any idea what it means?

BTW - I'm compiling for API level 23.  And YES, I know Camera2 is recommended but it's too muck work to re-port my code.

**UPDATE**

I think it may be a duplicate question, but the answers were sermons about not using deprecated features - I seek a solution. I tried everything I could think of: @SuppressWarnings( "depecation" ); ProjectProperties:JavaCompiler:Error/Warnings settings, etc. - but still they persist. I guess maybe (as greg-449 suggested in his 2nd comment) I'm SOL.

BTW - I can't find the Java->Editor->Syntax setting anywhere. Where is that puppy hiding?

Comment: The classes are marked @Deprecated. You can change the strikethrough in the 'Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring' preferences.

Comment: I suspected it was due to deprecation, but I tried suppressing deprecated warning every way I could fineL

Comment: Suppressing the warning does not stop Eclipse showing the strikethrough.

Comment: See UPDATE to question.

Comment: 'Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring' is in the Preferences - 'Window > Preferences' on Windows/Linux or 'Eclipse > Preferences' on macOS.

Comment: The suggestion above (greg-449, Preferences) work perfectly. No more strikethrough! Yaaay!